# Можно ли считать сложной русскую графику?

Tags: русская-графика

А. Русская графика – это практически идеальная система обозначения звук/буква. 10 гласных букв представляют  5 гласных звуков  (их твердый и мягкий варианты). Слоговой вариант  (согласный + гласный) – основа письма (например: за/ря).  Даже йотированные гласные (Я, Ё, Ю, Я)  фактически обозначают два звука (согласный «й» + гласный).  Даже отдельно стоящий согласный    - это тоже бывший слоговой вариант (ме/лъ – ме/ль), где  Ь обозначает бывший редуцированный гласный, который и сейчас можно услышать в виде краткого призвука, особенно при обучении чтению.

Единственная проблема для идеально построенной системы – это непарные по твердости/мягкости шипящие, но и эта проблема  решена хотя и в ручном режиме, но наилучшим образом, все остальные варианты были бы значительно хуже.

Б. Но и эта система нас не устраивает, кажется сложной.  Чтобы понять, КАКОЕ ПИСЬМО ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ СЛОЖНЫМ, можно привести цитату из книги Ж. Агалаковой «Все, что я знаю о Париже»:

«Как я ни старалась, так и не смогла добиться от моих парижских друзей ответа на вопрос: почему они пишут пять букв, а произносят одно-единственное «Ю»? Потом где-то прочла, что в древности, когда грамотных было крайне мало, а бумажные документы уже были в обороте, писари брали с клиентов мзду за каждую букву, вот и накручивали.

Думаю, это шутка. Но как тогда объяснить, что во французском в конце каждого слова есть буква, которая не произносится, но непременно пишется?! И что существует пять разных способов оформления звука «о» (в одном из них задействованы аж четыре буквы) и семь способов обозначения «е» (максимум три буквы)?

Сами французы испытывают серьезные трудности в письме. По-настоящему грамотных среди них очень немного. Не так давно один уважаемый писатель выступил с открытым письмом в «Либерасьон» с предложением (и он был далеко не первый!) провести, наконец, реформу и упростить орфографию. Писатель честно признался, что не умеет грамотно писать.

Дискуссия обрела такой масштаб, что Министерство образования было вынуждено официально заявить, что никакой реформы не ожидается, что французская грамматика — НАЦИОНАЛЬНОЕ ДОСТОЯНИЕ И КУЛЬТУРНОЕ БОГАТСТВО . Заявление вывесили на интернет-сайте Министерства. В нем было 119 ошибок".

Comment: К вопросу о сложности русской графики

1) И. п., ед. ч.: слово, ружьё, ружйо

2) р. п., ед. ч.: слова, ружья, ружйа

3) д. п., ед. ч.: слову, ружью, ружйу,

4) в. п., ед. ч.: слово, ружьё, ружйо,

5) т. п., ед. ч.: словом, ружьём, ружйом,

6) п. п., ед. ч.: о слове, о ружье, о ружйэ.

Участники олимпиад по русскому языку обязаны знать, что в словах "ружьё", "ружья", "ружью", "ружьём", "о ружье" символ "ь", величаемый мягким знаком, ничего не смягчает, а является сугубо разделительным знаком.

Comment: Могу сказать Вам по большому секрету, что на самом деле это вовсе не разделительный знак. Это всё тот же "ер", "разбойник, бездельник и лодырь", который под этот знак маскируется. Сравните: Мария - Марья. Здесь "ер" ничего не разделяет, а обозначает, как и раньше, очень короткий гласный, после которого буква Я читается как "йа" (как и после любого гласного).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Можно хотя бы по той причине, что чётких критериев простоты или сложности графической системы не существует. Что русскому хорошо, то немцу - смерть. Мы привыкли читать и мыслить по-русски, соответственно нам наша графика кажется проще, чем французская, но французу проще будет казаться французская система.

Я не особо разбираюсь во французском, но даже из этого текста и общих знаний можно сделать выводы, что несмотря на сложность правильно текст написать, прочитать его для носителя языка особых проблем не составляет. Увидев слово, любой француз его прочтёт так как его произнёс писатель. В русском же мы такой картины не наблюдаем. Я пишу слово "замок", а вы не знаете на какой слог я поставил ударение.

Если углубляться ещё дальше в графику, то 33 буквы не всегда лучше 26 французских. Имея русскоязычную фамилию "КошелькОв" мне, если её записывают, приходиться произносить  её с вологодским оканьем и эканьем, иначе могут записать неправильно. Причём даже правильная запись фамилии сделанная от руки, не гарантирует правильного прочтения. Как меня только не называли! И Комельков, и Котелков, и Кашликов, и Кашляков, и и даже Кошёлкин. В латинском алфавите, количество схожих в написании букв меньше, чем в кириллическом.

Так что, для того чтобы сказать сложна наша графическая система или нет, нужно сперва определить, а каковы критерии сложности и простоты. А вот это уже вряд ли возможно.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы София определила меру сложности графики и процедуру определения (нахождения) указанной меры.

Comment: Да легко. Допустим, русский, француз и англичанин услышали незнакомое слово из 7 звуков. Каждый из них сделал звуковую запись слова  в соответствии с фонетикой своего языка (в русской записи без отражения фонетического чередования). Теперь они записывают слово буквами в соответствии с графикой своего языка. Где  меньше вариантов, графика того языка проще.

Comment: @София, тогда нужен ещё и тот, кто потом эти записи прочитает, и его чтение должно совпасть с прочтением записавшего. Да и то, таким образом вы лишь выясните в каком языке больше звуков и более строгие нормы фонетики, а не графики. На русском невозможно записать звонкую согласную на конце слова, два варианта для звука [w], башкирская Өфө у нас стала Уфой, хотя ближе к оригиналу  "Офё", в то время как немец без труда бы записал как Öfö или Oefoe, при этом в немецком я встречал с пяток вариантов для звука [ш':].

Comment: Я хотела бы разделить наше соревнование на два этапа: фонетический и графический. Фонетику разных языков, действительно, сравнивать сложно (или сложнее). Что касается графики, то наши соискатели уже имеют фонетическую запись слова на родном языке, с использованием своей фонетики. Задача - обозначить эти звуки буквами.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы София соревновалась, например, с behemothus'ом.